An Error popup when I trying to import library from Transformers using Hugging face
I am trying to use the Hugging Face library, specifically the PatchTSMixerForPrediction module, but I'm encountering the following error. Based on my research, it seems that this module is not included in the transformers package by default. Could anyone help me figure out how to download or install this library?.
My Code is
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, PatchTSMixerForPrediction

and the error pop up is:
ImportError: cannot import name 'PatchTSMixerForPrediction' from 'transformers'

I assume you are using and old version of Transformers. I am using 4.39.3 and it works. Which version do you have?

I am using Transformers version 4.30.2

Which Python version are you using? @Silentcloud

3.10.12. Could you maybe update Transformers version and see if it works?
